The connection between the English I and Arabic ع
I'm asking this question as a bilingual Arabic/English speaker but a complete linguistics layman. But I noticed that the letters "I" in English and "ع" in Arabic are both homophones for the word "Eye" (عين in Arabic). This similarity fascinates me and I could not find any information about it from a Google search. Is there a connection there or is it just a coincidence?
Thanks!

The Arabic isn’t really a homophone: the name of the letter is the word ‘eye’, so they’re the same word. Conversely, ‘I’ and ‘eye’ in English only started sounding the same during the Great Vowel Shift – if you go back to Old English, ‘I’ was ic (iċ, pronounced like ‘itch’) or ih (pronounced like ich in German), whereas ‘eye’ was ēage – completely different, both in spelling and pronunciation.

These are coincidences. In fact Latin “I” is historically related to the Arabic ي and Arabic ع is historically related to Latin “O”, at least as far as letter shapes are concerned.

Many Semitic languages will show this pattern, and it's not a coincidence there. The Phoenician writing system (and possibly its predecessors) had a letter called ʕayn "eye" used for the /ʕ/ sound, and the Arabic, Hebrew, Aramaic, Syriac, and so on alphabets all descend from the Phoenician one. So these letters can be considered cognates—it's similarly not a coincidence that many of these writing systems have a letter that sounds like the word for "water", or "hand", or "ox", or "house". These letters are adapted from drawings of objects, and an eye is a conveniently easy-to-draw thing that starts with /ʕ/ (in most Semitic languages).
In English, though, it is just a coincidence. When the Phoenician script was adapted into Greek, the Phoenician names were mostly preserved—alpha, beta, etc—but this wasn't the case when the Greek script was adapted for Etruscan and the Etruscan script adapted for Latin. (It's unclear which of those two transitions discarded the old names.) Now, instead of being called something like yad (e.g. Greek iota), the letter I was just called by the vowel sound it made, i. And this name was transmitted from Latin to various other languages using the Latin alphabet.
Throw in a few thousand years of sound changes, and the English word for "eye" also ended up being a single vowel. But this really is a coincidence: it comes from earlier ēage (compare German Auge), which is not a single vowel sound.

The currently preferred theory is that these “"drawings of objects” are modelled on Egyptian hieroglyphs .

@fdb Oh absolutely, and I agree with that theory; I think the Proto-Sinaitic glyphs are pretty conclusive. I just didn't want to complicate the answer too much.
